# How to properly use redis with servicestack in a multi-thread environment?

Tags: multithreading, redis, servicestack

I assumed that we should use basicredisclientmanager or pooledredisclientmanager?
I tried this

```
private void dddddd()
{
    for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
    {
        var client = new BasicRedisClientManager(new string[] { "host1", "host2", "host3" }).GetClient();
        //do something with client
    }
}
```

This loop runs fine for the first 100 plus but after that, I always got an error "Unknown Command Role"?? What is that and how to fix it? I need help!

I also tried to make a new class called MyRedisMgr and created a static property to create some sort of singleton but it didn't work either.

```
public BasicRedisClientManager MyMgr = new BasicRedisClientManager(new string[] { "host1", "host2", "host3" });
```

And then I use it like

```
for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
{
    var client = MyRedisMgr.MyMgr.GetClient();
    //do something with client
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the documentation on the [proper usage of Redis Client Manager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) which should only be used as a singleton.

The `BasicRedisClientManager` doesn't have any connection pooling so every time you call `GetClient()` you're opening a new TCP connection with the redis-server. Unless you understand the implications you should be using one of the Pooled Redis Client Managers, e.g: `RedisManagerPool`.

You also need to always dispose the client after its used so that it can either be re-used or the TCP connection disposed of properly.

So your code sample should look like:

```
//Always use the same singleton instance of a Client Manager
var redisManager = new RedisManagerPool(masterHost);

for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++)
{
    using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
    {
        //do something with client
    }
}
```

The "Unknown Command Role" error is due to using an old version of Redis Server. The [ROLE](http://redis.io/commands/role) command was added in redis 2.8.12 but this API should [only be used if your using redis-server v2.8.12+](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/c8f4d4099f96f2948f1ee12ea41d2e9f90476d26/src/ServiceStack.Redis/RedisClient.cs#L1121), so you shouldn't be getting this error by default. You can avoid this error by upgrading to either the [stable v3.0 or old 2.8 versions of redis-server](http://redis.io/download) which has this command.

If you want to continue using an older version, use the [INFO](http://redis.io/commands/info) command to check what version you're running then tell ServiceStack.Redis what the version is with:

```
RedisConfig.AssumeServerVersion = 2600; //e.g. v2.6
RedisConfig.AssumeServerVersion = 2612; //e.g. v2.6.12
```

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I'm trying to find. Just one more question, how to dispose the client after I done? I never manually do it, I thought the GC will handle it automatically, no?

Comment: @shawhu if you use it within a `using {}` statement it's disposed automatically, otherwise you need to call `.Dispose()` on it yourself.